# Calculate XP needed for next Level using this simple algorithm?

Tags: mathematics

I am currently calculating the Levels in my game using the following forumla:

```
player.level = mathFLOOR(mathMAX(1, 0.05 * mathSQRT(player.score)) * (1 + player.kd / 10));
```

So the level is based on the persons total score and their kd. However I am now trying to figure out a formula for calculating the percentage of the score/kd you need to progress to the next level. If this is not possible, how could I do it with just this formula:

```
 player.level = mathFLOOR(mathMAX(1, 0.05 * mathSQRT(player.score)));
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I missed something here doing this ...

```
var progress = 0.05 * mathSQRT(player.score)) * (1 + player.kd / 10);
```

... will get you a value of how far the user has "progressed".

The level is that value rounded down to the nearest integer or 1 with ...

```
player.level = mathFLOOR(mathMAX(1, progress));
```

.. the progress between the current level and the next is therefore something like ...

```
var toNextLevel = progress - player.level;
```

... that will give you something like 0.1 for 10% or 0.34 for 34%

Comment: Wouldnt that just give me the difference by which the level was floored? Because essentially you are making the level = progress. The mathMax(1, ...) is just to make sure you are never below level 1.

Comment: level is essentially the round number or whole integer values of progression, the progress on the current level is the bit after the decimal place or the remainder converted to a percentage. To answer your question, yes this basically is the difference by which level is floored. Is that not what you were after?